# The name 'content' does not exist in the current context

Tags: javascript, c#, umbraco

I get this error, what am i doing wrong?

`
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

```
namespace Umbraco.Course.Controllers
{
[MemberAuthorize(AllowType = "IntranetUser")]
public class LikesController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public int LikeStatus(int id)
    {
        var contentService = Services.ContentService;
        var memberService = Services.MemberService;
        var relationService = Services.RelationService;

        var member = memberService.GetById(Members.GetCurrentMemberId());

        var post = contentService.GetById(id);

        if (!relationService.AreRelated(content, member, "likes"))
            relationService.Relate(post, member, "likes");

        var likes = relationService.GetByParent(post, "likes").Count();

            post.SetValue("likes", likes);

            contentService.PublishWithStatus(post);
            return likes;

        }
    }
  }`
```

Comment: Where the content is defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With reference to your code replace

`if (!relationService.AreRelated(content, member, "likes"))`

with

```
if (!relationService.AreRelated(post, member, "likes"))
```

and try it out,

Answer (score 3):

`if (!relationService.AreRelated(content, member, "likes"))`

The variable content is not defined.